# Array Nodes in Lua

Tags: arrays, lua, reference, nodes

I have an issue I'm trying to solve with my lua scripts. I am writing a branching narrative system that uses lua to modify strings on-the-fly. At the moment I'm using a nested system that takes into account every single decision. The inefficiency of this system is that multiple lines of code are repeated when I could instead reference the nodes of what I'm trying to make.

This is the basic code structure

```
return    
{
objectName = "",
npcDialog = "",
speech = "",
options = 
{},
actions = 
{
    {
        objectName = "",
        npcDialog = "",
        speech = "",
        options = 
        {},
        actions = 
        {}
    }
}
```

}

As you can see the actions array is nested and leads to very clunky code over-time that is hard to manage efficiently.

Instead, what I'm trying to achieve is something closer to this

```
local dialog1 = {
objectName = "",
npcDialog = "",
speech = "",
options = 
{
    "pick me",
    "don't pick me"
},
actions = 
{
   dialog2,
   dialog1 
}
```

}

```
local dialog2 = {
objectName = "",
npcDialog = "",
speech = "",
options = 
{
    "you silly goose",
    "why did you do this"
},
actions = 
{
    function () end,
    function () end
}
```

}

However, I'm fairly new to lua coding and when I try to do this it comes out with errors that I don't know how to debug.

Does anyone have suggestions?

This is a visual conversation layout which branches off depending on player choices.
[Conversation Layout][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZwel.png

Comment: Instead of references, you can use names of the nodes.  For example: `actions = {"D1_name", "D2_name"}`, and a separate table would find a dialog by its name: `all_dialogs = {["D1_name"]=dialog1, ["D2_name"]=dialog2 }`